# Drupal Notify Module email themeing

Tags: 7, theming

I am using [Notify](https://www.drupal.org/project/notify) module for new content notification to registered users.

The email send by notify module is in plain text format. I want to theme the email and add image or video thumbnails for embedded videos.

I searched the web but couldn't find a solution. Can someone help me, please?

Thanks